# php using filename as a condition for if/else statement

Tags: php, if-statement

I need help with a php if/else statement - I am placing an iframe with tracking pixel on a site and I want a certain iframe to appear for the index.php page, but a different iframe for all other pages.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<?php if($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == 'index.php'){?>
    <iframe src="HOMEPAGEURL" HEIGHT=1 WIDTH=1 FRAMEBORDER=0></iframe>
<?}else{?>
    <iframe src="SITEPAGESURL" HEIGHT=1 WIDTH=1 FRAMEBORDER=0></iframe>
<?}?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried checking what `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` contains on the index page? I think it'll be `/index.php` (note the slash).

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'index.php') !== false) {
```

Or:

```
if(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'index.php') {
```

Comment: Of course, these will also run the 'index page' branch for pages like `/subdir/index.php`.

Comment: As a side note, does `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` still return `index.php` when it is not explicitly in the URL? i.e. `www.example.com/` vs `www.example.com/index.php`

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe src="<?php echo basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'index.php' ? $HOMEPAGEURL : $SITEPAGESURL ?>" HEIGHT=1 WIDTH=1 FRAMEBORDER=0></iframe>
```